# W3 Validation of HTML form

Tags: php, html, validation

When im trying to validate my page on http://validator.w3.org/ i get one error that says

> Line 118, Column 44: there is no attribute "onClick"

But when I change the onClick to just onclick i get about 40 new errors and almous al of them is complaining about the character, they want me to change the caracters to the HTML format, but If i do that my PHP script stop working.

This is one of the rows that the validator is complaning about after I change onClick to onclick

```
<input type="text" name="enterprise" id="enterprise" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['enterprise']) ? $_POST['enterprise'] : '' ?>" />
```

and this is my onclick string

```
<input type="button" value="Clear" onclick="window.location.reload();return false" />
```

Is there another way I can reload the page or how can I write the input type php scrip so it validates.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is DTD-specific behavior. Are you using an XHTML DTD declaration?

Comment: See: http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/#h-4.2

Comment: Actually, I'm not sure what you're saying with the two different markup examples. What you're saying doesn't seem to make sense.

Comment: My DTD is Transitional.
I just want the code to validate, but i get errors in the php strings

Comment: I just readed that its the output data that you need to validate, not the code that you wrote. Thats what I was doing. =/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the W3 validator will complain if it finds any language it doesn't recognize and it's not normal in a webpage, such as php. You should pass your page trough a php server and then copy the final HTML in the validator.

Answer (score 0):

There is 3 Method to do it with Html/JS,

```
<input type="button" value="Reload" onClick="window.location.reload()"/>
<input type="button" value="Reload" onClick="history.go(0)"/>
<input type="button" value="Reload" onClick="window.location.href=window.location.href"/>
```

Notice: You can use AJAX technology to refresh page without reloading all elements like images, css files...etc.

Comment: Did you understand the *real* problem?